# Spring MVC Dynamic Data(CRUD Operations) Table inside a form

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, datatable

1.I have a form, bind with one model Attribute - on submit on am getting my model object with data

2.Now I have multiple data tables and input fields of all columns of the respective table,with its Save/Edit/Delete Buttons ->inside my main form

3.Now I want to add/remove/edit records to my tables - and on final submit of Form, it will go to my controller with all records, also I have list of objects of all the tables with my Main model attribute.

Please suggest/help me on this